# babylon doesn't accept text in text box

Tags: babylon

babylon 10 on windows 8.0
it was working fine, but now when I write in a word (or I click on a word in an open file) the word is too low, it misses the text box and gets covered by the language tabs and thus is very hard to see, although it still functions.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and also tried installing babylon 9 instead, but so far no good.

Answer (score 0):

okay, I reinstalled babylon 10 (using their official installer, which I downloaded directly from the babylon site), this time without uninstalling first. In other words, I installed exactly the same thing on top of an existing installation.

And the problem went away! and babylon remembers all my dictionaries and licenses and settings, too.